# Saving part of state of calling activity when creating another one

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a tabhost in my first activity and Im calling another activity sometimes; to handle some details. I need to remember the last tab selected in my first activity when the second one returns. Problem is the first activity is getting destroyed and created again and onSaveInstanceState is not getting called. The only option which I can think of is to write the last tab selected to external memory and read it back, which seems a little extreme considering this is just one tag. Is there any other option? I cant avoid the second activity (I had tried to change that to another fragment--fragment calling another fragment-- but that didn't work so well for me)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save small amounts of data in Android, you can always use `SharedPreferences`. [Here is a good example on how to use it.](http://androiddeveloperspot.blogspot.de/2013/01/sharedpreference-in-android.html)

And there are some other storage options for Android listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)